# How to modify sealed columns (Powershell)?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, powershell

I'm trying to build and customize a group calendar list created with "Group work site" template. I have stumbled upon some sealed columns, like "All day event". I need to modify them, therefore I need to remove "Sealed" property off them.

I found a nice looking article:
http://brainstormit.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-remove-sealed-column-in.html

```
$site = SPSite(http://server_name:server_port)
$web = $site.RootWeb
$list = $web.Lists["topics"]
$field = $list.Fields["Page Content"]
$field.Sealed = $false
```

My problem with the above is that my site resides at something like
`http://SPServer/site1/site2`
so it's a site within a site (fortunately, we don't need to go deeper ;). When I try:
`$site = SPSite("http://server/site1/site2")` (with or without quotes)
I get an error:
`Get-SPSite : Cannot find an SPSite object with Id or Url`

So, my question is: How to get to the lists stored in sites within sites? Maybe there's some other way, like using site ID? How can I find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subsites are SPWeb objects, not SPSite.  SPSite is a Site Collection.  SPWeb is a SharePoint site.

Use Get-SPWeb for your subsites.

Answer (score 0):

Or alternatively if you have access to the server, use SharePoint Manager to navigate to the list column and set the Sealed property to false